# Custom UIPageControl dots are misplaced on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I have a weird behavior with custom `UIPageControl`.
I subclassed it and in `setCurrentPage` method I draw custom dots.

- In iOS 6 on load they just miss.
- In iOS 7 the dots are misplaced.

In both iOS's dots are being positioned correctly only after I change the slide.

I tried the following methods without success:

```
[customPageControl updateCurrentPageDisplay];
[customPageControl updateConstraints];
[customPageControl sizeToFit];
[customPageControl.currentPage = 1];
```

### The code:

```
@implementation ProfilePagesPageControl

@synthesize originalSubviews;
@synthesize dotsHeight;

- (void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];

    [self updateDots];
}

- (void)updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < self.subviews.count; i++)
    {
        UIView* dotView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int j = dotView.subviews.count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            UIView *view = [dotView.subviews objectAtIndex:j];
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

        int widthForDots = [Utils getDeviceBounds].width - Constraints.Gap * 3;
        int effectiveWidth = widthForDots / self.subviews.count - Constraints.Gap;
        int effectiveGap = (widthForDots - (effectiveWidth * self.subviews.count) + Constraints.Gap * 3) / self.subviews.count;

         int effectiveHeight = dotsHeight;
        if (i == self.currentPage)
            effectiveHeight = effectiveHeight + 3;
         else
            effectiveHeight = effectiveHeight - 3;


        CGRect dotViewFrame = dotView.frame;
        dotViewFrame.origin.x = effectiveWidth * i + Constraints.Gap + effectiveGap * i;
        dotViewFrame.origin.y = self.frame.size.height / 2 - effectiveHeight / 2;
        dotViewFrame.size.width = effectiveWidth;
        dotViewFrame.size.height = effectiveHeight;
        dotView.frame = dotViewFrame;

        UIView *dotSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                  0,
                                                                  dotView.frame.size.width,
                                                                  dotView.frame.size.height)];

        if (i == self.currentPage)
            dotSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        else
            dotSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [UIUtils roundCorner:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) forView:dotSubView];

        ProfileSlideView *slideView = [self.originalSubviews objectAtIndex:i];
        RevUILabel *label = [[RevUILabel alloc] initWithSize:13];
        label.text = slideView.name;

        label.frame = CGRectMake(dotSubView.frame.size.width / 2 - label.frame.size.width / 2,
                             dotSubView.frame.size.height / 2 - label.frame.size.height / 2,
                             label.frame.size.width,
                             label.frame.size.height);

        [dotSubView addSubview:label];
        [dotView addSubview:dotSubView];
    }
}
@end
```

### The iOS7 look:

[image: The iOS7 look]

---

### The iOS6 look:

[image: The iOS6 look]:

---

### After slide look:

[image: After slide look]

---

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Could you post your code for setting custom dots?

Comment: need  screenshot of the problem. for better understanding..

Comment: have you call `setCurrentPage` method in viewdidload?, try it.

Comment: Yes. I wrote it in question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `updateDots` somewhere else (such as viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear) so they can be set up before you switch any pages. If you only call `updateDots` in `setCurrentPage` it will only be called once you switch the page the first time.